# linkedin javascript api domain is restricted to localhost

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I'm trying to use linkedin javascript api, but when I run a script I get an error 'javascript api domain is restricted to localhost'. Does anyone know what is that? Please, help!

Answer (score 8):

1. Go to https://www.linkedin.com/secure/developer
2. Click on the application name you're using.
3. Add your domain to *JavaScript API Domains:*
4. Save changes.

This should fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

1 create a new app on LinkedIn devloper
2.in URL you should write path like this 
http://localhost/linkdin/index.php/
then save 
after it your problem will be resolve